# How to add custom message to slack with variable in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, slack

I want to send slack message after Jenkins build a task like this:

```
My_Job - #10 Success after 18 sec (Open)
My Report: http://my_domain/report_20181017195500.html
```

So I tried to set this varialbe in the `Execute shell` area of the job in Jenkins:

```
...
DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`
MY_REPORT="report-$DATE.html"
```

Add this to the `Include Custom Message` of the `Slack Notifications` block:

```
My Report: http://my_domain/${MY_REPORT}
```

But when I check the Slack channel, it send me:

```
My_Job - #10 Success after 18 sec (Open)
My Report: http://my_domain/${MY_REPORT}
```

How to set `$MY_REPORT` the true value in this case?

---

## Edit

I have tried `EnvInject` [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). Set this code to the `Execute shell` block:

```
...
echo MY_REPORT=$(echo "http://my_domain/report-$DATE.html")  > /var/lib/jenkins/var.properties
```

It can read value from the `/var/lib/jenkins/var.properties` which set in the `Inject environment variables to the build process` of `Build Environment` block. But can't write into that file from `Execute shell`.

Comment: Did you tried `"http://my_domain/${MY_REPORT}"` instead of $MY_REPORT?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: Were you able to make this working?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
slackSend channel: 'channel_name', message: 'My_Job - ' + BUILD_NUMBER + '\nMy_Report:' + JENKINS_URL
```

Comment: in which context do you run this?

Comment: it can be inside the steps

Comment: Sorry I dont follow, can you provide an image ot a link to some reference on this method?

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are acessible for building custom slack notifications. In my case I'm using variables from GitLab webhooks configured to trigger builds to customize slack messages:

So this message definition:

[image]

Results in this slack notification:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I found that I needed to:

1. Write the environment vars to a var.properties file from the main "Execute shell" build step.
2. Add an "Inject environment variables" build step reading from the same file. The step must be after the main shell step.
3. Use it in Slack Notifications after both those steps are completed